# Batch file for repairing Vmware VMDK files

Tags: batch-file, vmware, repair

I have been trying to write a batch script that will allow me to fix broken `vmdk` files that are used for VMWare all in one go, rather than having to run the command manually on every single file. Having never really worked that much with batch files I'm floundering a little! Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this isn't working?

```
set /p WMWorkstationDir = Enter the directory of the VmWare Workstation install, and press enter;
set /p VMFolderToFix = Enter the directory where the VMDK files live that you wish to repair, and press enter;
Rem this is to set up working names in the batch file for the directories specified, helping abstract it
cd VMFolderToFix
for %%X in (*.vmdk) do WMWorkstationDir vmware-vdiskmanager -R
Rem trying to get the repair command to run on all the vmdk files in the target location
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

See if these changes give you a help:

The `"%%X"` will be replaced by the filename, for each file.
You may need an output filename too and you can try `"%%~nX-fixed%%~xX"`

```
cd /d "%VMFolderToFix%"
for %%X in (*.vmdk) do WMWorkstationDir vmware-vdiskmanager -R "%%X"
```